# testing with break command in C# and i am getting a error

Tags: c#, break

I am pretty new to C# and i was learning until i saw break command so i started testing with it , i don't know much commands , i am still learning so spare me pls this is the code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            int t = 4;
            int f = ++t;
            if(t<3)
            {
                if (f < 3)
                    Console.WriteLine("No");
            }
            else if(t>3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes");
                if(f>3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DOUBLE YES");
                    break;
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(f);
            Console.WriteLine(t);
        }
```

the error is  **No enclosing loop out of which to break or continue**

Thank you!

Comment: breaks are used to exit loops such as for, foreach, while and switch statements https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break

Comment: if your intention is to leave the program, while not using any kind of loop, use `return` instead of `break`

Comment: wow thank you for so fast answers , i love yall thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer here is pretty straightforward.  A `break` is used to break out of a loop (`for`, `foreach`, `while`, as well as `switch` statements).  Right now you're not inside a loop, you're just outputting to the console within conditional statements.

Example below taken from [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break).

```
class BreakTest
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            if (i == 5)
            {
                break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        // Keep the console open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

breaks are used to exit loops such as for, foreach, while and switch statements.

According to your if-else logic, you don't need any breaking. The block will exit automatically.

If you want the following two lines to be executed:

```
         Console.WriteLine(f);
        Console.WriteLine(t);
```

You can't use return.